# How to Implement in a ModelAdmin Form in Django a Inline inside a Inline?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

Basic explanation:

I'm working on a catalog app that has Product as a model that has a 1-N relationship with  Galleries. Each Gallerie has N Photos.

I need to customize the add/edit form of my model Product as follows:

- In the same form can add/edit Galleries (as Inlines, easy, implemented). [1]
- But in each Gallerie Inline i can add Photos in the same Product Form

Is that possible?

[1]:

```
class GallerieInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Gallerie
    extra = 1

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GallerieInline,]
```

Answer (score 0):

in the inline you must put a list_display with related object :S

Other way its create a view and with javascript get the images and append to inlines